# how to view next element when check box is checked

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have CheckBox and textbox I am trying to remove the CssClass hidden  after user check the box I tried using next but it didn't work can someone help me

HTML

```
    <ul id="sortable">
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rep_sortable">
    <ItemTemplate>

   <li class="ui-state-default">
       <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Body") %>  
       <asp:CheckBox ID="chb_com"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Completed")  %>' oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"/>
       <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_reminderID" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReminderID")  %>'/>
       <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtb_whyclosed" CssClass="hidden"></asp:TextBox>
   </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function () {
    console.log("vbvsdvs");
    $("input[type=checkbox]").next("input:text").removeClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function only selects the next element. It does not find the next element that matches the selector. (The selector is only a filter)

To make your code work either move the checkbox directly next to the textbox so next will find it:

```
<li class="ui-state-default">
   <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Body") %>         
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_reminderID" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReminderID")  %>'/>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="chb_com"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Completed")  %>' oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"/>
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtb_whyclosed" CssClass="hidden"></asp:TextBox>
</li>
```

Or use [nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) which will search all of the sibling elements after the current one:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function () {
    console.log("vbvsdvs");
    $(this).nextAll("input:text").removeClass("hidden");
```

Note, you should also use `$(this)` inside the click callback otherwise you will affect every textbox that is after a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function () {
    $("#txtb_whyclosed").removeClass("hidden");
})
```

OR

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
    $("#txtb_whyclosed").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: That id selector will not work, because in the rendered markup the ID will be different.

Comment: $("input.hidden").removeClass("hidden");  try this then

Comment: $(":text.hidden").removeClass("hidden");

Comment: $(":text",$(this).parent()).removeClass("hidden");

Answer (score 0):

You are using a repeater here, so you should give your checkboxes and textboxes a class name to identify and differentiate from the other inputs:

HTML:

```
   <li class="ui-state-default">
       <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Body") %>  
       <asp:CheckBox CssClass="checkbox" ID="chb_com"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Completed")  %>' oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"/>
       <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_reminderID" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReminderID")  %>'/>
       <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtb_whyclosed" CssClass="hidden text"></asp:TextBox>
   </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

JS:

```
$("input.checkbox").on("click", function () {
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
         $(this).next(".text").removeClass("hidden");
    else
         $(this).next(".text").addClass("hidden");
})
```

Comment: nextUntil does not work like that. From the jQuery documentation - "Get all following siblings of each element up to but **not including** the element matched by the selector". This will try to remove the hidden class from the hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    var txtBox = $(this).nextAll('input:text');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        txtBox.removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        txtBox.addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```